# Split data in SQLite column

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database that looks similar to this:

```
----------   ------------   ------------
| Car    |   | Computer |   | Category |  
----------   ------------   ------------
| id     |   | id       |   | id       |  
| make   |   | make     |   | record   |  
| model  |   | price    |   ------------
| year   |   | cpu      |
----------   | weight   |
             ------------
```

The `record` column in my `Category` table contains a comma separated list of the table name and id of the items that belong to that Category, so an entry would look like this:
`Car_1,Car_2`.

```
=====================
|     Category      |  
---------------------
| id  |  record     |
---------------------
|  1  | Car_1,Car_2 |
---------------------
```

I am trying to split the items in the record on the comma to get each value:

```
Car_1
Car_2
```

Then I need to take it one step further and split on the `_` and return the `Car` records.

So if I know the `Category` id, I'm trying to wind up with this in the end:

```
----------------   ------------------
| Car          |   | Car            |
---------------|   -----------------|
| id: 1        |   | id: 2          |
| make: Honda  |   | make: Toyota   |
| model: Civic |   | model: Corolla |
| year: 2016   |   | year: 2013     |
----------------   ------------------
```

I have had some success on splitting on the comma and getting 2 `record`s back, but I'm stuck on splitting on the `_` and making the join to the table in the `record`.

This is my query so far:

```
WITH RECURSIVE record(recordhash, data) AS (
  SELECT '', record || ',' FROM Category WHERE id = 1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT
         substr(data, 0, instr(data, ',')),
         substr(data, instr(data, ',') + 1)
    FROM record
   WHERE data != '')
SELECT recordhash
  FROM record 
 WHERE recordhash != ''
```

This is returning

```
--------------
| recordhash |
--------------
| Car_1      |
| Car_2      |
--------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you willing to change your table design? I hate to say it but it is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your recursive CTE works as expected then you can split each of the values of `recordhash` with `_` as a delimiter and use the part after `_` as the `id` of the rows from `Car` to return:

```
select * from Car
where id in (
  select substr(recordhash, 5)
  from record
  where recordhash like 'Car%'
)
```

Comment: That give me exactly what I need, but is it possible to programmatically set the table name too? So instead of hardcoding 'Car' in the query, it would come from the recordhash?

Comment: You have 2 tables: Car and Truck. If you want results for both tables this can be done with a UNION and by checking the 1st part of the recordhash, but still the names of the tables will be hardcoded. Is this that you want?

Comment: Well, the full database will have around 15 tables. I just updated my question to replace the Truck table. The tables will all be different. I am trying to make a query that I only have to pass the Category id into to get back a list of records. If the table name has to be hardcoded, then there isn't much we can do about it.

Comment: A query can't return different number of columns depending on a parameter. It always returns the same. What you need can be accomplished with a programming language.

Comment: Probably 95% of my queries will all be returning the same type. Guess I'll have to do something different for the rest. Thank you so much for your help!